# Java Swing Compiled Application does not show

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I created a Swing application in Eclipse and after I was done I compiled it, with no errors or warnings, but after compilation, I opened the jar file and there was no window showing. It shows it is running the dock but there is nothing else. However, when I run it in Eclipse, it works fine.

I tried decompiling with Archive Utility and running manually and it works fine too.

I will be including all the code and directories:

Unarchived Manifest File

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: swing.MainSwing
```

Directory (as shown in Eclipse):

```
| Cookie Clicker
    | src
         | swing
             | DetailsPanel.java
             | MainFrame.java
             | MainSwing.java
             | package-info.java
             | PM.java
    | src/res
         | cookie_icon.png
         | cookie.png
```

MainSwing.java

```
package swing;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MainSwing extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8231889836024827530L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new MainFrame("Cookie Clicker");
                frame.setSize(500, 500);
                frame.setResizable(false);
                ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
                if (PM.getImage("cookie_icon.png", classLoader) != null) {
                    frame.setIconImage(PM.getImage("cookie_icon.png", classLoader));
                }
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

DetailsPanel.java

```
package swing;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class DetailsPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8854226121488997931L;
    private JLabel cookies;
    private long cookiesBefore = MainFrame.cookies;

    public DetailsPanel() {
        this.setBackground(new Color(0, 51, 102, 255));
        this.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        TitledBorder border = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Stats");
        border.setTitleColor(Color.WHITE);
        setBorder(border);

        this.cookies = new JLabel("Cookies in total: " + MainFrame.cookies);
        this.cookies.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        this.cookies.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        JLabel cookiesPerSec = new JLabel("Per second: ");
        cookiesPerSec.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
        PM.setGC(gc, 0, 0);
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        PM.setGCWeight(gc, 2, 0);
        add(cookies, gc);

        PM.setGC(gc, 0, 1);
        add(cookiesPerSec, gc);

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new updateSeconds(cookiesBefore, cookiesPerSec), 0, 1000);
    }
    public void updateCookies() {
        String amount = String.valueOf(MainFrame.cookies);
        cookies.setText("Cookies in total: " + amount);
    }
    class updateSeconds extends TimerTask {
        long cookiesBefore;
        JLabel cookiesPerSec;
        public updateSeconds(long cookiesBefore, JLabel cookiesPerSec) {
            this.cookiesBefore = cookiesBefore;
            this.cookiesPerSec = cookiesPerSec;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            long cookiesNow = MainFrame.cookies;
            cookiesPerSec.setText("Per second: " + String.valueOf(cookiesNow - cookiesBefore));
            cookiesBefore = cookiesNow;
        }
    }
}
```

MainFrame.java

```
package swing;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7853386173600171822L;

    private DetailsPanel detailspanel;
    public static long cookies = 0;
    private BufferedImage img_cookie = null;
    public MainFrame(String title) {
        super(title);

        // Layout
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

        // Create Components
        JButton reset = new JButton("Reset");
        reset.setOpaque(true);
        reset.setBackground(new Color(30, 30, 30, 255));
        reset.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        reset.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        reset.setFocusPainted(false);
        JButton cookie = new JButton();
        detailspanel = new DetailsPanel();

        //Set Button image
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        BufferedImage temp = PM.getImage("cookie.png", classLoader);
        if (temp != null) {
            img_cookie = PM.getImage("cookie.png", classLoader);
            cookie.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img_cookie.getScaledInstance(80, 80, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
            cookie.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        } else {
            cookie.setText("add");
        }

        // Cookie button animation
        cookie.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt) {
                if (img_cookie != null) {
                    cookie.setIcon(new ImageIcon(
                            img_cookie.getScaledInstance(100, 100, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)
                            ));
                }
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent evt) {
                if (img_cookie != null) {
                    cookie.setIcon(new ImageIcon(
                            img_cookie.getScaledInstance(80, 80, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)
                            ));
                }
            }
        });

        // Add Components
        Container c = getContentPane();
        c.setBackground(new Color(255,247,217,255));

        PM.setGC(gc, 0, 1);
        PM.setGCWeight(gc, 10, 0);

        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gc.gridwidth = 2;
        c.add(reset, gc);


        PM.setGC(gc, 0, 0);
        PM.setGCWeight(gc, 1, 2);

        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        gc.gridwidth = 1;
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        c.add(detailspanel, gc);


        PM.setGC(gc, 1, 0);
        PM.setGCWeight(gc, 1, 0);

        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        c.add(cookie, gc);

        // Listener
        cookie.addActionListener(new CookieClickListener());
        reset.addActionListener(new ResetClickListener(reset));
        reset.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt) {
                reset.setBackground(new Color(46, 46, 46, 255));
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {
                reset.setBackground(new Color(10, 10, 10, 255));
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent evt) {
                reset.setBackground(new Color(30, 30, 30, 255));
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent evt) {
                reset.setBackground(new Color(30, 30, 30, 255));
            }
        });
    }
    // Add cookie after click
    private class CookieClickListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            cookies++;
            detailspanel.updateCookies();
        }
    }
    // Reset
    private class ResetClickListener implements ActionListener {
        JButton reset;
        public ResetClickListener(JButton reset) {
            this.reset = reset;
        }
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            cookies = 0;
            detailspanel.updateCookies();
            reset.setBackground(new Color(10, 10, 10, 255));
        }
    }
}
```

PM.java

```
package swing;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class PM {
    public static void setGC(GridBagConstraints gc, int col, int row) {
        gc.gridx = col;
        gc.gridy = row;
    }
    public static void setGCWeight(GridBagConstraints gc, double x, double y) {
        gc.weightx = x;
        gc.weighty = y;
    }

    public static BufferedImage rotate(BufferedImage image, double angle) {
        int w = image.getWidth();    
        int h = image.getHeight();

        BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D graphic = newImage.createGraphics();
        graphic.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        graphic.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), w/2, h/2);
        graphic.drawImage(image, null, 0, 0);

        return newImage;
    }
    public static BufferedImage getImage(String path, ClassLoader classLoader) {
        try {
            File f = new File(classLoader.getResource(path).toURI());
            return ImageIO.read(f);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

package-info.java

```
/**
 * 
 */
/**
 * @author mac
 *
 */
package swing;
```

**EDIT**
I found the problem. This was based off 2 links:

First to find what was wrong: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669455/exported-runnable-jar-file-from-eclipse-doesnt-seem-to-execute)

Second to find the solution: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055189/why-my-uri-is-not-hierarchical)

So the problem was that in PM.java I could not do:

```
File f = new File(classLoader.getResource(path).toURI());
return ImageIO.read(f);
```

But instead I have to get the resource as a stream like this:

```
return ImageIO.read(classLoader.getResourceAsStream(path));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run `MainSwing`, you'll need to be in the parent of the folder containing the class files (e.g. the parent of "swing", given above as `~/Cookie Clicker/`). Then you can run it like

```
java -cp . swing.MainSwing
```

**Note** the package is part of the class name. See, [Setting an Application's Entry Point: The Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) for more details.

Comment: Did not work.

`    $ java -cp . swing.MainSwing`
`    $ Error: Could not find or load main class swing.MainSwing`

Comment: @MoonCheesez Make sure your `.java` files are compiled to `.class` files. The above is correct, if the folder `swing/` contains `MainSwing.class` (and the other class files).

Comment: Yes, they are classes.

Comment: @MoonCheesez What directory are you in (`pwd`), and what is the result of `ls -l swing/MainSwing.class`?

Comment: /Users/mac/Desktop/Cookie Clicker/swing, this is the unarchived folder of the jar file.

Comment: @MoonCheesez `cd ..`, your class is part of the `swing` package. Please read my answer again.

Comment: Yes, now it works, however, the jar still does not work. What is the fix for this?

Comment: @MoonCheesez Please read [Setting an Application's Entry Point](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html); add `Main-Class: swing.MainSwing` to the jar's `manifest`.

Comment: Is there a possible way that Eclipse does this for me?
I would also like to add (Sorry I did not add it above) that I did compile previous versions and they worked.

Comment: You could try walking through all the wizards in `Export > Java > Runnable JAR file`. If that doesn't work, ask another question; with all the details about what you've tried.

Comment: Alright, that was what I did for all the versions. I will start another question.